# how to exclude a certain folder when using scandir in php

Tags: php, scandir, preg-grep

I am using scandir to list all the files in a directory. But there should be an exception for `./`, `../` and `tmp` folder.

I already have this to exclude the dot and double dot:

```
$files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));
```

How can i add `tmp` folder to it? (name of the folder is tmp)

Comment: As an aside: the code you're using will exclude _any_ file or directory whose name starts with a dot. This may or may not be something you actually want.

Comment: i agree.! But a name started with a dot is not allowed. It is filtered in the input

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
   $toRemove = array('.','..','tmp'); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir);
   
   $result = array_diff($cdir, $toRemove);
```

It's easier than `preg_grep`

Answer (score 1):

I would choose for this solution, because of already mentioned by @duskwuff, your current code excludes all the files which start with a `.`

```
$files = array_diff( scandir($dir), array(".", "..", "tmp") );
```

Comment: I agree! this is the better way to do it. works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a regex you can try to take a look at the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$files = preg_grep('/^(?!tmp|\.{1,2})$/', scandir($dir));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like that if you want to stick with regex

`$files = preg_grep('/^(?!tmp|(?!([^.]))).*/', scandir($dir));`